# How to get WordPress Wesitelogo

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I am a newbie with Gatsby.
So, I would like to get my website logo defined in the WordPress administration. Here is how I did it:

```
`import React from 'react';
import {graphql, StaticQuery} from 'gatsby';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import  Img  from  'gatsby-image';

    const SiteInfo = () => (
        <StaticQuery query={graphql`
        {
            file(name: {eq: "logo"}) {
                relativePath
                childImageSharp {
                  fluid {
                    originalImg
                  }
                }
            }
            site {
                siteMetadata {
                  title
                }
            }
        
        allFile(filter: {name: {eq: "logo"}}) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
                url
                relativePath
              }
            }
        }
        
        allWordpressWpMedia(filter: {title: {eq: "logo"}}) {
            edges {
              node {
                title
                source_url
              }
            }
          }
    }
      
      
    `
    } render = {data => (
        <BasicInfoWrapper>
            <Sitelogo>
                <Img src={data.allWordpressWpMedia.edges.node.source_url} alt="Logo" />
            </Sitelogo>
            <SiteTitle>
                {/*data.site.siteMetadata?.title || `Title`*/}
            </SiteTitle>

        </BasicInfoWrapper>
    )}/>
    );
    export default SiteInfo;
```

`

unfortunately it doesn't work and I get the following error: TypeError:

```
`can't access property "source_url", data.allWordpressWpMedia.edges.node is undefined`
```

So I turn to you so that I can succeed in doing it

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tested your query in the GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`)?

Comment: Yes, it work very well. Here is the results: {
  "data": {
    "allWordpressWpMedia": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "title": "logo",
            "source_url": "http://localhost/hellopomelo/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo.png"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter the position of the nested `edges`, since it's an array.

```
 <Img src={data.allWordpressWpMedia.edges[0].node.source_url} alt="Logo" />
```

However, this won't work to display the image using [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/). You should use a native `img` tag:

```
 <img src={data.allWordpressWpMedia.edges[0].node.source_url} alt="Logo" />
```

If you want to use `gatsby-image`, you need to retrieve some additional data using fragments or raw fields. An ideal query of `gatsby-image` should look like:

```
  query {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "blog/avatars/kyle-mathews.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(width: 125, height: 125) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then, you will be able to:

```
export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
    <Img fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />
  </div>
)
```

To summarize, you can't just use `src` attribute because Gatsby needs to parse the image using transformers and sharps to treat the image and create GraphQL node schemas.

You need to transform your query to something like:

```
const allMedia = graphql`
  query {
    allWordpressWpMedia {
      edges {
        node {
          source_url
          localFile {
            publicURL
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

For further details take a look at [this article](https://dimitr.im/optimize-loading-images-wordpress-gatsby).

Comment: ooohhh Great ! thank you, thank you very mutch..it work with the first method.